# MS Access Data Structure Problems with Parent/Child self-joins

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a database with the following tables:

- BeliefsT

  - BeliefID (AutoNumber)
  - Belief (Short Text)
- ReasonsToAgreeT

  - ArgAgreeID (AutoNumber)
  - ConclusionAID(Lookup to BeliefsT)
  - ReasonToAgreeID (Also a Lookup to BeliefsT)
- ReasonsToDisagreeT

  - ArgDisagreeID (AutoNumber)
  - ConclusionDID (Also a Lookup to BeliefsT)
  - ReasonToDisagreeID (Also a Lookup to BeliefsT)

Problem 1: I can't count the number of times that a ConclusionAID has been selected in the ReasonsToAgreeT Table.

This is my first attempt:

```
SELECT BeliefsT.Belief, ReasonsToAgreeT.ReasonToAgreeID, ReasonsToDisagreeT.ReasonToDisagreeID
FROM (BeliefsT 
         LEFT JOIN ReasonsToAgreeT 
            ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToAgreeT.ConclusionAID
      ) LEFT JOIN ReasonsToDisagreeT 
            ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToDisagreeT.ConclusionDID
GROUP BY BeliefsT.Belief, ReasonsToAgreeT.ReasonToAgreeID, ReasonsToDisagreeT.ReasonToDisagreeID
ORDER BY BeliefsT.Belief;
```

It just sort of lets you look at all the values, but doesn't do anything...

I can also just look at one table at a time, but that doesn't really get me anything:

```
SELECT ReasonsToAgreeT.ConclusionAID, Count(ReasonsToAgreeT.ReasonToAgreeID) AS CountOfReasonToAgreeID
FROM ReasonsToAgreeT
GROUP BY ReasonsToAgreeT.ConclusionAID;
```

This is the closesest I can get, for my report data source, but it counts duplicate empty values, because my relationships are messed up:

```
SELECT BeliefsT.Belief, ReasonsToAgreeT.ReasonToAgreeID, ReasonsToDisagreeT.ReasonToDisagreeID
FROM (BeliefsT 
        LEFT JOIN ReasonsToAgreeT 
          ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToAgreeT.ConclusionAID
      ) LEFT JOIN ReasonsToDisagreeT 
          ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToDisagreeT.ConclusionDID;
```

When I include both the reasons to agree table and the reasons to disagree table, the relationships get all messed up, because they both look at the same belief table, and it tries to do a cross product, and everything gets messed up, and I can't accurately count the number of reasons to agree or disagree...

Comment: Please include that problematic SQL statement and narrow down your question excluding the non-essential parts. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell I added some SQL and removed my big picture end goal, and just mentioned my initial problem... I hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your business logic and problem definition is a bit unclear, so based on a qualified guess, the best possible SQL query solution you came out with is the following:

```
SELECT BeliefsT.Belief, ReasonsToAgreeT.ReasonToAgreeID, ReasonsToDisagreeT.ReasonToDisagreeID FROM (BeliefsT LEFT JOIN ReasonsToAgreeT ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToAgreeT.ConclusionAID) LEFT JOIN ReasonsToDisagreeT ON BeliefsT.BeliefID = ReasonsToDisagreeT.ConclusionDID;
```

If the only problem is `Null` values erroneously counted, then add `WHERE` clause `Not Is Null` referring the respective fields. Another option is to use MS Access SQL Conditional Operator `IIf(IsNull(SomeField), 0, 1)`.

Hope this may help. Best regards,